# change variable after collapse

Tags: statistics, stata

I am working on repeated cross-sectional data and I want to create a variable recording the annual rate of change of marriages according to 5 different age groups. My starting dataset contains a binary variable taking the value 0 for "non married" and 1 for "married" as well as the individual age-group and year. I thought to collapse my data in order to retrieve the average group value for each age and individual

```
collapse (mean) married,  by(year age)


year    prop.married    age
1992    .442865         27-31
1992    .75411          32-36
1992    .864637         37-41
1992    .900926         42-45
1993    .456798        27-31
etc.
```

How do i compute the annual change of rate for each age-group and possibly plot it (with a line for each age group over time)? I tried the following but it seems not to work:

```
bys age (year): gen cng= (prop.married[_n]-prop.married[_n-1]/prop.married[_n-1])
```

Thank in you in advance.

Comment: "seems not to work" needs to be fleshed out with details, but your closing parenthesis looks wrong. Change = (new - old) ./ old

Comment: The period or stop is illegal in variable names.